# Redshift Alter table command returns `Target table and source table attributes don't match.`

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift, airflow, etl

I have an airflow pipeline which creates a staging table from an existing table, loads data in it from a csv, and then the following alter command is executed.

```
ALTER TABLE "schema"."table"
            APPEND FROM "schema"."table_staging"
            FILLTARGET
```

I observed the following error is retuned occasionally, I simply dropped the original table and re-created it and it will work fine for few days, and then out of no where I'll encounter this again.

```
DETAIL:  
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Target table and source table attributes don't match.
  code:      8001
  context:   The source table and the target table have different sort keys. Both tables must use the same sort keys and sort style.
  query:     0
  location:  tbl_perm.cpp:2823
  process:   padbmaster [pid=19083]
```

I'm unable to figure out why it starts breaking all of a sudden.

Answer (score 0):

- Append does not work if the source and target tables definitions does not coincide.
- When some property is not set when creating a table, redshift usually takes control of it and changes it when he detects that is a better configuration.

That said, in the scenario you describe: probably the sort key of the original table is not set, so redshift determines it. Initially, sort keys match and there is no problem, but when redshift changes the sort key (of the original) the error raises again.

I recommend setting the sort key explicitly and/or use `CREATE TABLE staging (LIKE original)` since "Distribution style, sort keys, BACKUP, and NULL properties are inherited by LIKE tables" ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW.html))